# No Action Bar shown when using AppCompat-Theme and Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Okay, I'm gonna keep this as simple as possible:

I have two styles, one for users of API 21 (Lollipop) and a default one for everything between API 14 and 21.

When the parent theme inherits from the AppCompat library (e.g. Theme.AppCompat.Light) there is no action bar shown when using Activity classes.

I know I can use ActionBarActivity for this. The problem is that I use the theme Material.Light when running on version 21 which isn't compatible with ActionBarActivity. What's the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best solution for this problem?

Pick one action bar implementation and stick with it. Either use `appcompat-v7` for all API levels, or use the native action bar for all API levels. Note that the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport looks a lot like the `Theme.Material` action bar, as part of the vision of `appcompat-v7` is to bring the Material Design aesthetic to older devices.

Comment: Using appcompat-v7 for everything looks like the best for me. Just one question though. If I use Theme.AppCompat.Light for all API levels and I run it on a device of API 21, is this exactly the same as using Theme.Material.Light for this API level? In other words: will the support library theme recognize if you're running on the newest API and use all Lollipop features?

Comment: @JentheThienpondt: "is this exactly the same as using Theme.Material.Light for this API level?" -- no. It is visually very similar, but it is an independent implementation, and AFAIK it does not delegate to the native implementation on API Level 21+ devices, though you would have to examine the source code to confirm that.

Comment: Thank for the explanation! I was wondering if the Toolbar (v7 version) could be of help here? If I use a toolbar, I think I can use both appcompat and material-themes, or is this not recommended?

Comment: @JentheThienpondt: "If I use a toolbar, I think I can use both appcompat and material-themes" -- not really. There are two implementations of `Toolbar`, one native and one in `appcompat-v7`. You either use one or the other and would need a theme to match.

Comment: Clear, then I'm gonna stick with the appcompat theme. Thank for your input.